# Webscraping Pandas ("No tables found")

Tags: pandas, web, screen-scraping

through pandas I would like to extract a table from an internet page, the problem is that on some pages there are no tables and it returns an error.
I would like to know how to solve this problem.
Thanks

```
from typing import ItemsView, Text
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
import bs4, requests, webbrowser
from pandas.io import html 

URL = ('03-01-2022.html')

DataFrame = pd.read_html(URL)

table = DataFrame[0]
table.T.drop_duplicates().T
# Fahrt
Fahrt = table['Fahrt']
separator = ""
```

Comment: It would help us if you could share a sample HTML file where this error occurs

Comment: With other pages it works, let me explain, it is a website where I can see my work shifts, when I have a working day for example 06.01.2022, the table is found because my shifts are listed, but in the free days, the page does not contain any table, I use selenium to download the page.